Ask for help for the suddenly shut down of Jupyter Notebook
I want to change the startup path of my jupyter notebook and find it suddenly shut down after I click the shortcut icon. I can hardly find out why.
What I did for the change was just to change the path in profile of the Juperter notebook. Is there any thing I can do to turn eveything back to normal?
